# "Despite ill, Lisa went on stage" or "Despite being ill, Lisa went on stage"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-structure, subordinate-clauses, adverbial-phrases

I am not sure if this sentence "*Despite ill, Lisa went on stage*" sounds ok?

In [this book](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=C3fIJNPQfrsC&pg=PA97&lpg=PA97&dq=reduced%20adverb%20clause%20cambridge&source=bl&ots=5V6HsOK40I&sig=w0R4ezH5y8AHyKeAK5I8NNC_D9o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjm-LPJlYXPAhXIoZQKHVnJDFYQ6AEIJjAC#v=onepage&q&f=true), it said "*Despite being ill, Lisa went on stage*".

But, I think "*Despite ill, Lisa went on stage*" and "*Despite being ill, Lisa went on stage*" are the same.

Comment: They are not the same. The "clause of concession" example provided is: _Despite being ill, Lisa went on stage._ If the conjunction _although_ is used instead of _despite,_ the clause could be reduced to _Although (she was) ill._ _Despite,_ though, is a preposition here and must take a noun or noun phrase, not an adjective like _ill,_ as an object,.

Comment: You may say "Despite her illness" if you want to avoid using a verb.

Comment: "Despite ill, Lisa went on stage" is incorrect. It will be understood, it doesn't stand out too badly (it's something that a native speaker _might_ say, even though it's wrong), but it is still wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complement of **despite** is a nominal or something that suffices as one.

**ill** is an adjective (in the context of the example) and doesn't work there.

Despite *her illness*...

Despite *being* ill...

Despite *the fact that* she was ill....

Answer (score 0):

"Ill" by itself like that is incorrect. It isn't "She ill", it's "She feels ill" or "She is ill".

You could definitely say "Despite illness, ..." though.

Comment: This site is for people who are learning English. When you answer a question, it's not just about providing the right answer.  Can you explain your answer so that readers can learn from it?